# Cloud function only retrieving first item in database, not all

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function working with a Firebase realtime database to retrieve some data. There are several items in my database, however the function is currently only retrieving the first item. I am unsure why this is happening as there is a for loop I am using to iterate over all the items. Here is my code:

```
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var ref = admin.database().ref('users')

exports.checkusers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            let users =  [];
            users.push({
                key: childSnapshot.key,
                data: childSnapshot.val()
            })
            return res.json(users);
        });
    })
})
```

I have tried to fix this but this is the Google style of doing this so I am unsure why this isnt working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413242/firebase-realtime-database-does-value-event-fires-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because for each element your array reinitialises. Try pulling the users out of the for each.

```
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var ref = admin.database().ref('users')

exports.checkusers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let users =  [];
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            users.push({
                key: childSnapshot.key,
                data: childSnapshot.val()
            })
        });
    })
    return res.json(users);
})
```

Comment: made the changes as suggested but its still having the same issue, only pulls the first item in the database

Comment: Updated the answer. Please try this

Comment: Thank you! Works for me now, honestly very puzzled how I managed to miss that.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things wrong.  First, you should only call `res.json()` a single time with all of the data you want to send, not inside a forEach loop.  Second, you should use `once()` instead of `on()` to query a single time, and use the promise that it returns to know when the query is complete.  Start with this, and work your way to a final solution:

```
exports.checkusers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        res.json(snapshot.val());
    })
})
```